# Oracle Constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I am working on a small school project using oracle database. I have created some tables and two of them are Mobile (Mobile_Number,Status_Flag) Status_Flag shows if a number is active or not and there is another table Owner_Mobile(Owner_Id FK,Mobile_ID FK). Now I should write a Constraint that prohibits the insert operation if the corresponding Status_Flag is N for the specified number. I tried to make it using sub query but this is not possible.

the constrain should be applied to OWNER_MOBILE table of course. For example if I say: INSERT INTO OWNER_MOBILE(25541,042536) the constrain should check the Mobile table and see if the Mobile 042536 is active or not . If the number is not active the insert statement should generate a error

Comment: Please edit your question and include more information - specifically, it would be helpful to know which table is supposed to have a constraint added to it. Also include the DDL for defining both tables. Thanks.

Comment: As best I can figure, there isn't a way to accomplish what you want using a constraint in Oracle. You'll need to use a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the trigger or another PL/SQL API for this but you should take into account ACID transaction principles. Let's consider the case when flag value = 0 should prevent insertion:

```
SQL> create table mobile (mobile_id int primary key, flag int)
  2  /

SQL> create table owner_mobile(owner_id int,
  2  mobile_id int references mobile(mobile_id))
  3  /

SQL> insert into mobile values (1,1)
  2  /

SQL> commit
  2  /

SQL> create or replace trigger
  2  tr_owner_mobile
  3  before insert on owner_mobile
  4  for each row
  5  declare
  6    l_flag mobile.flag%type;
  7  begin
  8    select flag into l_flag
  9    from mobile where mobile_id = :new.mobile_id;
 10  
 11    if l_flag = 0 then
 12      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unavalable mobile');
 13    end if;
 14  end;
 15  /
```

In the code above I simply select flag and rely on the retrieved value - I don't care of ACID.

In the first transaction I update flag value but don't commit:

```
SQL> update mobile set flag = 0 where mobile_id = 1;
```

In the second transaction I insert into owner_mobile and get the success:

```
SQL> insert into owner_mobile values(1,1);

1 row inserted.
```

Next, I commit the first transaction and later - the second one. What I get then:

```
SQL> select * from mobile;

 MOBILE_ID       FLAG                                                           
---------- ----------                                                           
         1          0                                                           

SQL> select * from owner_mobile;

  OWNER_ID  MOBILE_ID                                                           
---------- ----------                                                           
         1          1
```

Seems this is not what I expect.

I can use select for update to prevent inconsistent behavoiur:

```
SQL> update mobile set flag = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> delete from owner_mobile;

1 row deleted.

SQL> commit;

SQL> create or replace trigger
  2  tr_owner_mobile
  3  before insert on owner_mobile
  4  for each row
  5  declare
  6    l_flag mobile.flag%type;
  7  begin
  8    select flag into l_flag
  9    from mobile where mobile_id = :new.mobile_id
 10    for update;
 11  
 12    if l_flag = 0 then
 13      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unavalable mobile');
 14    end if;
 15  end;
 16  /
```

Now do the same:

```
SQL> update mobile set flag = 0 where mobile_id = 1;

1 row updated.
```

Second transaction is waiting because parent row is locked:

```
SQL> insert into owner_mobile values(1,1);
```

After commit in first transaction I get in the second one:

```
SQL> insert into owner_mobile values(1,1);
insert into owner_mobile values(1,1)
            *
error in line 1:
ORA-20000: Unavalable mobile 
ORA-06512: at  "SCOTT.TR_OWNER_MOBILE", line 9 
ORA-04088: error in trigger 'SCOTT.TR_OWNER_MOBILE'
```

So whatever you do to achieve requirements you will have to consider transaction isolation.